# I need to find 5 most used words by using dict method and also words provided by moodle system

Tags: python-3.x

```
import sys  
girdi = sys.stdin.read()
girdi = girdi.lower()
girdi = girdi.replace('.','')
girdi = girdi.replace(',','')
girdi = girdi.replace("'","")
girdi = girdi.replace("-",' ')
sözlük={}
for word in girdi.split():
    if word not in sözlük:
        sözlük[word] = 1
    else:
        sözlük[word] += 1
for key in sorted(sözlük, key=sözlük.get, reverse=True):
```

girdi = input & sözlük = dictionary
Hope i do well with counter thing but I am having problems with returning 5 most used words.
so what should i do ?

Comment: Side note - putting regional characters in your code, into variables definition might backfire. It's a good practice to try to keep it down to Latin characters + relevant special characters, avoid umlauts ;)

Comment: Thanks for heads up!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```py
from collections import Counter
import re

#instead of all the replacing - do this on your raw data:
x=Counter(re.findall("\w+", girdi))

#top 5 values:
y=sorted(x.values(), reverse=True)[:5]

#top 5 words, along with respective counts
res=dict(filter(lambda z: z[1] in y, x.items()))

#to get the words only:
res.keys()
```

Comment: Well i am very new to this language so i couldnt really done the job :( I should practice more thanks for help

Comment: No worries - please mark it as an answer to close off your question ;)